# Does chromium(III) oxide react with or dissolve in liquid sulfur dioxide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solubility, transition-metals, reference-request, oxides

Liquid $\ce{SO2}$ (b.p. −10 °C) is known as a [versatile solvent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfur_dioxide#As_a_reagent_and_solvent_in_the_laboratory) (yet not particularly pleasant to work with) for a wide range of organic and inorganic compounds having limited solubility in conventional solvent systems. I recall that chromium(III) oxide should chemically interact with sulfur dioxide, but I cannot find a reputable source to back up this fact.

There is a related post on [Reddit — Any tips for a stubborn frit filter?](https://www.reddit.com/r/chemistry/comments/oo8nvm/any_tips_for_a_stubborn_frit_filter_chromium/) describing a problem with $\ce{Cr2O3}$ precipitation being stuck on the glass frit filter. Neither fusion with flux nor dissolution in alkali are suitable because they are guaranteed to permanently damage the frit. Oxide particles seem to be not fine enough to dissolve in strong acids, including oxidizing ones, to a significant degree or at a noticeable rate.

I think it would be interesting to know whether liquid $\ce{SO2}$ could potentially serve as a solvent for similar cases with “uncooperative” $\ce{Cr2O3}$ where relatively mild ambient conditions are expected.

Comment: I don't think it's soluble - SO2 is useful because it's unreactive and I don't think you could dissolve sth like Cr2O3 without reaction.

Comment: @Mithoron I fail to find either confirmation or refutation (even with a reaction). That's the issue.

Comment: Well, that would be an argument against, unless your google-fu failed you ;)

Comment: @Mithoron Now I want to research this further to prove you wrong, but I'm not sure where else to look for:( This is mildly irritating.

Comment: Well, I think it doesn't dissolve in anything without reaction and SO2 is particularly unreactive, so probably nobody even tried. Still, it would be pretty cool if it did ;)

Comment: related https://www.researchgate.net/post/Does-anyone-know-a-way-to-solve-Cr2O3

Comment: $\ce{Cr2O3}$ is one of the rare metallic oxides known to be insoluble in concentrated acids. it needs molten $\ce{NaHSO4}$ heated to a high temperature to pass into solution. This is why $\ce{Cr2O3}$ is probably insoluble in $\ce{SO2}$